# How to clear the input for a Zeppelin machine?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I'd like to clear the input memory in my zeppelin instance.

I'm running a command that takes data from S3 and runs some transformations.

Somehow, the input according to the executors tab in Spark is up to 1.4TB.

It's listed under "Total Input" on the "Executors" page

I tried to clear my cache to bring it down to zero, but it won't budge

I'm running spark 2.x and tried `spark.catalog.clearCache()` and `sqlContext.clearCache()`

How do I clear the input memory?

Comment: Words have meaning. 1.4TB of **input** means 1.4 TB of data have been **flowing into** the system. It means nothing about what amount has been discarded (by filters), what combination of memory & disk have been used to store the remainder at the time, and whether that data is still stored anywhere now.

Comment: Did you really see the phrase "input memory" anywhere?

Comment: Yep, the Apache Zeppelin dashboard says INPUT on the executors screen